# how to detect fake mobile traffic without use user agent in PHP?

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how to detect fake mobile traffic?

I was detecting device type (mobile or not mobile device) 
by analyzing User Agent value in header from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in PHP.

But I know now that exists an User Agent Switcher.

Comment: if it's in an http header, it can be faked. there is no 100% reliable way of detecting a user's "type".

Comment: Trusting request headers will always be vulnerable to spoofing since they are part of the client-generated request.

Comment: attach Your host to CloudFlare and let them to defend Your server. It gives nice features like: DDOS defending, Scrape shield, static content caching

Comment: @CollinD, do you know if exists a method to detect by server?

Comment: @FernandoOliveira Like Marc said, there is no foolproof 100% way to do it since the client has to tell the server what it is.

Comment: @num8er but will detect bot traffic? websites like traffic-bots, hitleap, addmefast.

Comment: @FernandoOliveira yes, when it see many request from same source it puts intermediate page where user have to write hard for bot detect capcha. You can realize same functionality but it's not easy and quick, because You've to "invent custom web server" that will analyze requests and do blocking. Or You can log requests to db and check if request from same ip was early than 5 seconds early more that 5 times just block the IP on app level for 5 minute, that will make site scraping harder.

Comment: Can You give the link to Your project? (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want to defend from site scrapers, software ddos attacks (don't downvote me (: ) You've 3 ways:

1) use some service like CloudFlare to defend from parasitic traffic (ddos, site scraping). `will be easy and will take less time.` - **CALL IT "THIRD-PARTY SERVICE"**

2) develop web server that will intellectually detect parasitic requests by principle: "less time between requests". `needs understanding of http(s) requests and proficiency developing system level apps.` - **CALL IT "INVENTING CUSTOM WEB SERVER WITH SELF INVENTED FIREWALL"** (:

3) make "software firewall" inside Your apps code that will log requests to some database (better use redis-server with storing data with timeout) and detect again by "less time between requests" principle and set block for IP address for 1 minute or more. `easy to develop, but will make performance loads on database, better use no-sql storages like redis or caching memcache.`  - **CALL IT "I'LL DO IT MYSELF WITH WHAT I HAVE"**

**My choise**: CloudFlare (1) because no time to invent the wheel, no time to write and modify custom code and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the device used by the user by using $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
with this you can check site is visited by BOT or any other device,
https://templatebench.com/detect-device-type-in-php/
Here you can check all tutorial to get device type of the user